# JsonManagedReference vs JsonBackReference

Tags: java, jackson

I would like to know the difference between `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` in Jackson?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

> @JsonManagedReference is the forward part of reference – the one that
>   gets serialized normally. @JsonBackReference is the back part of
>   reference – it will be omitted from serialization.

So they really depend on the direction of your relationship

```
public class User {
    public int id;
    public String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    public List<Item> userItems; 
} 

public class Item {
    public int id;
    public String itemName;

    @JsonManagedReference
    public User owner; 
 }
```

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: @RoutesMaps.com looks like they dropped the patch version from the URLs, checkout the latest URL: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html Here is their github.io repo: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/tree/master/docs/javadoc

Answer (score 12):

- @JsonManagedReference -> Manages the forward part of the reference and the fields marked by this annotation are the ones that get Serialised
- @JsonBackReference -> Manages the reverse part of the reference and the fields/collections marked with this annotation are not serialised.

**Use case:**
You have a one-many or many-many relationships in your entities/tables and not using the above would lead to errors like

```
Infinite Recursion and hence stackoverflow - > Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
```

The above errors occurs because Jackson (or someother similiar) tries to serialise both ends of the relationship and ends up in a recursion.

@JsonIgnore performs similiar functions but the above mentioned annotations are preferable.

Answer (score 7):

As write Rajat Verma, his solution works perfectly. Thanks man you saved me lot of time and anger :-)

> **The important Part:**
>   You need define fields as `List`, I had that as `Set` before and this solution NOT WORKING (appears as infinite loop)!

I add my solution:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Long.class)
public class Agent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subscribers")
    @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "List", example = "[1,2,3]") // for Swagger
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true) // show only id of Topic
    private final List<Topic> subscribeTopics = new ArrayList<>()
}

 @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Long.class)
 public class Topic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "topic_agent",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_topic_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_agent_id"))
    @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "List", example = "[1,2,3]")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    private final List<Agent> subscribers = new ArrayList<>();
 }
```

Comment: Nothing were working to me because I was using Set as well. Changed to list and all work fine. Why?!!! Arghhhh

Comment: I found out that when I use List instead of Set everything works fine without applying any of the solutions. Just change form Set to List and every thing starts to work. No need of any annotation at all. I would like to understand If someone can explain.

Answer (score 5):

`@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` are designed to handle this two-way linkage between fields, one for Parent role, the other for Child role.

> For avoiding the problem, linkage is handled such that the property
>   annotated with @JsonManagedReference annotation is handled normally
>   (serialized normally, no special handling for deserialization) and the
>   property annotated with @JsonBackReference annotation is not
>   serialized; and during deserialization, its value is set to instance
>   that has the "managed" (forward) link.

Comment: if @JsonBackReference annotation is not serialized, then how it gets "deserialized" without first being serialized ?