# JPA : Select parent and child with oneToMany relatinships

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

Implemented one to many relationship and select parent and child
I have a `onetomany` relationship and I want to do a query (select *)

Folders.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOLDERS")
public class Folders implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Folder_Author", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Authors author;
    // Getter + setter
}
```

Authors.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORS")
public class Authors implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Folder_Author", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable=false)
    private List<Folders> folders = new ArrayList<Folders>();
}
```

**My request :**

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Folders f");
return query.getResultList();
```

I got this result :

```
[
    {   
        "id":29,
        "noFolder":"0017",
        "author":{
            "id":9,
            "name":"Alpha",
            "service":null,
            "folders":[
                {"id":29,
                "noFolder":"0017",
                "author":{
                    "id":9,
                    "name":"Alpha",
                    "service":null,
                    "folders":[
                    {
                        "id":29,
                        "noFolder":"0017",
                        "author":{
                        "id":9,
                        "name":"Alpha",
                        "service":null,
                        "folders":[
                            ..
                            ..
            }
]
```

What's wrong in my code ? What is the problem when I execute query I got this result ..  .. I would like to get this result

```
[
    {   
        "id":29,
        "noFolder":"0017",
        "author":{
            "id":9,
            "name":"Alpha",
            "service":null,
            }
    }
]
```

Comment: you mean you want the 1-N field to be LAZY loading, and you set it to EAGER?

Comment: Yes you right, but when I tried lazy I got this error : `Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: business.entities.folders.Authors.folders, could not initialize proxy - no Session
 at rg.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:587)
 at `
..

Comment: also the `OneToMany` needs a mappedBy specifying to link both sides.

Comment: I updated it and now it is like : `@OneToMany(mappedBy="author", targetEntity=Folders.class,  fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<Folders> folders = new ArrayList<Folders>(); `

Comment: wtf is field "initiator" ? Should be "author" from the code you post

Comment: Sorry It is an error.. it is author ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `@JsonIgnore` on your collection field like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Folder_Author", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable=false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Folders> folders = new ArrayList<Folders>();
```

Comment: yes, but if I do it, how can I get values of the parent (Author) ? Like for each folders I would like to get his Author ...

Comment: @user1814879 You have to break the infinite loop using `@JsonIgnore` or else it never works. So you have to put on one-to-many side or many-to-one side.

Answer (score 2):

Use @JsonBackReference on the list of folders in the author class to prevent recursive serialization.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319358/jsonmanagedreference-vs-jsonbackreference)