# How to expose many to many relationship in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I am facing a issue.. I have a many to many relationship with jpa in spring boot, but I need to expose the following
product has many tags and tag has many product

if query product/1

```
{product:{name:"product 1"}, tags:[ tag1:{name:"tag 1"}, tag2:{name:"tag2"} ] }
```

if query tag/1

> `{tag:1, products:[ product1:[{name:"product 1"}, tag2:{product:"tag2"} ] }`

what is the way to expose this with rest with spring boot?
a example, url or and idea it would be useful.

Comment: not sure what you wanted.. are you looking for a way to map these to JPA entities?

Comment: ah sorry I already have the mapping working , but maybe u know when you try to expose it as rest (converted to json) there is a infinite recursion exception , because the both sides relationship.. what i am looking is a new point of view to expose it as rest like my example, maybe I am not facing well the problem and there is a best way

Comment: Try this link: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: So if you have the JPA mapping working then the problem is nothing to do with JPA, and everything to do with JSON, so remove the `JPA` tag from the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations to stop an infinite recursion from occurring when you try and serialise your JPA beans.

Have a look at some of these questions for further info:

- [Difference between @JsonIgnore and @JsonBackReference,
  @JsonManagedReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392733/difference-between-jsonignore-and-jsonbackreference-jsonmanagedreference/37394318)
- [JsonManagedReference vs
  JsonBackReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319358/jsonmanagedreference-vs-jsonbackreference?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

There are [multiple alternatives to stop infinite recursion](http://springquay.blogspot.com/2016/01/new-approach-to-solve-json-recursive.html):

1. `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`:

```java
@Entity
public class Product {
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
}

@Entity
public class Tag implements {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
}
```

2. `@JsonIdentityInfo`:

```java
@Entity
public class Product {
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@Entity
public class Tag implements {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
}
```

3. `@JsonIgnoreProperties`:

```java
@Entity
public class Product {
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("products")
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
}

@Entity
public class Tag implements {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("tags")
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
}
```