# Spring Boot REST Api - Response data is not showing expected results using 1:M relationship between entity classes

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, rest

So I'm trying to build a website using Spring Boot and React.

So far I have a registration form that is connected to my spring backend at **localhost:8080/api/test/customers** (Have endpoints for CRUD operations here)

This woks fine, and I can post form data to it from my React form, and I can view it in postman to get the expected response from the API.

---

But now I have another form on the site (A contact form where a user enters their name, email and message).

I have this API at **localhost:8080/api/form/contact** for GET and POST requests.

---

I have mapped the Entities 'Customer' and 'Contact Form' using a 1:M relationship which contains the customer id as a FK in the Contact Form table.

The thing is, since I added this, The response from the API is not what I'm expecting.

---

**The response goes on for like this for 200 lines in postman, just nesting the same stuff**

[**The GET request to the Customer API (registration)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pzx0.png)

[**The GET request to the Contact Form API**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAWkW.png)

---

**My Entity Classes**

**Customer.java** - Removed Validation Annotations to make it easier to read

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="customer_id")
    private int customerId;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email_address")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name="date_of_birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Column(name="mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private Set<ContactForm> contactForm;

    // default & arg constructor
    // getters and setters

}
```

---

**ContactForm.java** - Removed Validation Annotations to make it easier to read

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contact_form")
public class ContactForm {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="contact_form_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="email_address")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name="message")
    private String message;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    // default and arg constructor
    // getters & setters

}
```

---

**MySQL DDL for these 2 tables**

**customer**

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `customer_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mobile_number` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
)
```

**contact_form**

```
CREATE TABLE `contact_form` (
  `contact_form_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_form_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customer_id`)
)
```

**Controller class for customer**

[**Controller Class with standard endpoints, same for ContactForm Controller**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI9gC.png)

I cant post data to either endpoints anymore, Can someone please let me know why this is happening, I would like to have a record of the users and all their previous messages.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly suggest to look at the [DTO pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to expose your domain objects over REST, with just the necessary information included.

Exposing ORM entities directly is error prone, not abstracting API internals and can even create major security risks.

For example, create `UserDto` and `MessageDto` classes:

```
public class UserDto {
    private int customerId;
    private List<MessageDto> messages;
}

public class MessageDto {
    private String content;
    private String recipient;
    // other relevant fields
}
```

and return the `UserDto` (or a list thereof) from your rest controller method instead.

The actual problem you are describing is that your ORM mapping builds a circular graph between `Customer` and `ContactForm`. The `@OneToMany`/`@ManyToOne` relation seems to be not working correctly.

In general I would suggest to not map Entities in such a cyclic way, but make them navigable in only one direction (e.g. `Customer`->`ContactForm` or the other way round).
Cyclic mappings (and mapping big graphs in general) has IMO several issues:

- It can cause automatic, unexpected loading of very big parts of your database in memory for seemingly small queries.
- It can lead to unstructured domain model design.

The latter issue is arises when your application grows, and might be harder to fix later on:
Suppose your app and team grows, and multiple people should work on different parts mostly independently. So you refactor your existing code base, and create two modules: `customer` and `contact`.
`customer` holds basic data of customers (name, address, email, ...). It's sole purpose is to manage the lifecycle of customers (creating customers, changing the address or name, searching for specific customers, ...).
`contact` implements means to interact with your company: a contact form for customers, a contact form for people that are not your customers yet and a way for your employees to reply to those messages.

Now these two modules should be decoupled, so changes in one module impact the other module as little as possible.
To achieve that, you should have only well defined dependencies between the two modules, and no cyclic dependencies between modules in general.

If the code you built until that point navigates back and forth between entities of different "domains" via ORM graphs (or other methods for that matter), you will have a hard time splitting those things up.

Now, all of this is a bit far into the future, and still doesn't solve your problem at hand (in contrast to @Flavalacious answer).
I would only suggest to think about navigable mappings in general, if the dependency introduced between the classes is necessary and useful and what the implications could be further down the line.

Edit: elaborate on issues with cyclic mappings and deeper mappings in general.

Comment: I'll look into DTOs for sure. So you suggst it's best to have a unidirectional 1:M mapping rather than being accessible from the other entity as well ? (Bidirectional)

Comment: I elaborated on the architectural impacts of cyclic and navigable mappings in my answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This describes what problem you might have in the future because of bad entity modelling. In case you're looking for ways to define entity ownership, I suggest to look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21068644/14148807).

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of using DTO or not, you referred `Customer` which refers `ContactForm` which refers `Customer` again, causing a recursive reference to the object.

A simple way to avoid this is to use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`, which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31319631/14148807).

Another way to do it is to `@JsonIgnore` on the child object, depending on how your API interacts.

Both of these would tell Jackson to ignore the child object on Serialization.

Comment: You are correct, this solves the serialization problem at hand. I would still suggest to not introduce serialization-specific concerns on ORM-specific classes.